# Azure Active Directory tier/license types and its limitation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Looking for some official Microsoft documentations about Azure Active Directory tier/license types and its limitations but no luck

- Is there Basic tier of Azure Active Directory still available or
  retired?
- What is maximum number of users can be stored in Azure Active
  Directory tier wise?
- Tier wise pricing of Azure Active Directory
- Tier wise SLA details

Not sure details provided [here](https://www.gigxp.com/free-vs-basic-vs-p1-vs-p2/) are still valid & true to consider it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

- **[Basic no longer exists](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-is-phasing-out-the-basic-edition-of-azure-active-directory/)**.  The Free edition is included with a subscription of a commercial online service, e.g. Azure, Dynamics 365, Intune, and Power Platform.
- See [Service Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions) and [Feature Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing) Docs
- See [Pricing for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)
- See [Azure AD SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/active-directory/v1_1/)

Comment: Updated to include link for basic going away.

Comment: Link says about Azure AD resources. What are Azure AD resources?  users, groups, applications anything other than that?

Comment: How many user objects can be created in AAD with P2 license in specific? any  related documentation link?

Comment: P1 and P2 don't have any limits on objects in the directory but there are limits to the number of objects (uses, groups, etc) you can sync from on-prem.

Comment: AD Sync is totally out of scope in this discussion. My use case is only about direct creation of user in AAD. With that note, if my understanding of your above statement is correct, by owning P2 license I'm allowed to DIRECTLY CREATE 'n' number of USER objects in AAD without any restrictions. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, with the caveat there is a soft limit of 500,000.  To go beyond the default quota, you must contact Microsoft Support.  We have customers will millions of users in AAD so it has been done.

Comment: Heard from one of the Microsoft partners, though P1 and P2 don't have any limits on objects in AAD, still in single AAD the total number of USER objects is limited to 100,000. Could pls. confirm this cap limit on total number of user object is valid? If there is cap limit on no. of user objects in an AAD like 100,000 users, then this limit applicable for direct user creation on the AAD or only for AAD sync?